# Is there a transform in SSIS that lets me operate on current *and* previous row?

Tags: ssis, row

I am running a dataset from one SQL database into another, while summarizing it.  The starting database has over 3 billion records covering several years of readings from a couple thousand utilities meters.  I am running it through an SSIS package.  First I run the data through a script component that rounds off the timestamp to the nearest hour and converts it from UTC to local time.  Then an aggregate transform that groups the data by meter, reading type, and hour, giving me the min and max of the reading value.
I would like to subtract the max of the previous hour from the current hour to get a delta.  In SQL, I could use the LAG function.  I am thinking I could do a script component in SSIS that keeps the last meter, reading type, timestamp and max(value).  Then, if we are still on the same meter, I can get the delta.
But, is there a cleaner way?  Is there a transform that keeps the previous row, and lets me access it and operate on the values of both the current row and previous row?

Comment: You've identified the component: Script Component. I do worry though about the memory constraints you may encounter while doing all these async operations. It might make sense to stage the semi-conformed data into a table and then use the lag/lead functions to solve that step.

Comment: Can you import the raw data into a staging table and use the LAG function in a stored proc that moves the data to your final table?

Comment: IMHO the "cleaner" way is to do most of it in staging tables and T-SQL rather than SSIS, but "cleaner" is an objective term. I'm often struck by the frequency of this 'prior row' requirement and the lack of a built in component to do it.

Comment: I tried using a SQL stored procedure (using the LAG function), and that worked ok, but slow.  I am hoping SSIS will be able to handle it in memory and give me a considerable speed improvement.  The intermediate tables I had to use in SQL were the slow part of the process - 17 of the 25 minutes it took to run (I will have to run this twice daily as several million records are added daily to this huge vendor database).

Answer (score 0):

no there is no lag() in ssis, but you can implement it by using self join

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more?

Answer (score 0):

1. sorting
2. create a index (e.g. 1,2,3,4,5)
3. multicast
4. leftside (1,2,3,4,5), rightside (2,3,4,5)
5. self join 
   (leftside1 - rightside2, leftside2 - rightside3 ... leftside4 - rigthside5)
6. rightside is the 'next' of leftside

Comment: i used this method in ssis to simulate lag(), but this is not a good practice since 'sort' is always time-consuming; from my point of view, doing such a thing in data source using SQL would be better